# Python: how to format user into a date

Tags: python, input

input("Input Date of Birth: ")

Please can some tell me  how I manipulate the user answer and turn it into dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "force" the user to.

You can check if the date is valid though, for example like this:

```
import datetime
def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text,"%d/%m/%Y")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

inDate = input("Input birthdate (DD/MM/YYYY)\n")

isValid = validate(inDate)
```

The `isValid` will be a bool which will have `True` value if the date is correct, `False` otherwise.

If the date is not valid, ask the user again for a correct input.